# Multi-core decoding with android ffmpeg

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, android-video-player

Can anyone give me steps to do multi-core decoding with android ffmpeg.

I don't know where I need to start. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Start by explaining how you're interfacing with FFmpeg now.

Comment: with threaded compilation, on a multicore processor, ffmpeg will do pthread multi threading, which is multicore execution

Comment: @Brad: I built ffmpeg and using it via android-NDK.

Comment: @nmxprime: Can you give me more details? Which I need to configure with threaded compilation.

Comment: Thread detection is auto in ffmpeg.If ffmpeg can find `pthreads` library in standard path, it'll enable threaded support. check configure log to see if it enables. If not, then force it in config.h and link pthreads library